# Elasticsearch throughput on a single node

Tags: elasticsearch

I am building a steaming + analytics application using kafka and elasticsearch. Using kafka streams apps I am continuously pushing data into elasticsearch. Can a single node elasticsearch with 16GB RAM setup handle a write load of 5000 msgs/sec? The message size is 10KB

Answer (score 1):

There are many other conditions to consider, like cluster memory, network latency and read operations. Writing operations in Elasticsearch are slow. Also it seems like the indexes could grow quickly so performance might start to degrade over time and you'll need to scale vertically.

That said, I think this could work with enough RAM and a queue where pending items wait to be indexed when the cluster is slow.

Adding more nodes should help with uptime, which is a normally a concern with user-facing production apps.